# How to "paint" Google Maps tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I play a few games on my phone, and they're able to geolocate me, and turn my area into a playing field. I've done a LOT with with Google Maps api, and I see how they do a lot of it, but they apply a simple cartoonish layer to the map, roads are simple drawn version of roads, and the rest is just grass.

I don't understand how that happens in the apps.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?I'm sorry If differ.

http://datamaps.github.io/

Comment: That would work, but I didn't want to use D3. it doesn't have all the other options I'd need with google maps unfortunately.